# Как записать звук с устройства для записи по умолчанию используя NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

Смотрел код здесь - https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/5.php и здесь - https://toster.ru/q/405123

```
waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0; // является ли код 0 устройством по умолчанию?
```

Comment: Эти примеры не заработали? Или что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, в общем случае устройство по умолчанию не обязано иметь код 0. Получить код можно так:

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
/* ... */

[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern uint waveInGetNumDevs();

public const uint DRV_RESERVED = 0x0800;
public const uint DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID = (DRV_RESERVED + 17);
public const uint DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 18);
public const uint DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE = (DRV_RESERVED + 12);
public const uint DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 13);

[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "waveInMessage")]
public static extern int waveInMessage1(uint hWaveIn, uint msg,
    ref uint dw1, uint dw2);

[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "waveInMessage")]
public static extern int waveInMessage2(uint hWaveIn, uint msg,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder dw1, uint dw2);

//получает ID (номер) устройства записи по умолчанию

public static uint GetDefaultDeviceId()
{
    string endpid = "";
    var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

    using (enumerator)
    {
        var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Console);
        using (device)
        {
            endpid = device.ID;
        }
    }

    uint num = waveInGetNumDevs();
    StringBuilder sb;
    uint size = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        size = 0;
        waveInMessage1(i, DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE, ref size, 0);

        sb = new StringBuilder((int)size + 10);
        waveInMessage2(i, DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID, sb, size);
        ;
        if (sb.ToString() == endpid) return i;
    }
    throw new ApplicationException("Default device not found!");

}
```